# Using POST method for checkboxes is creating problems on "Reloading/Refreshing" that page

Tags: php, html

I am using 9 checkboxes to get input from user and using POST method to get the data. The problem is that when I try to reload that page, the browser shows me this message-

"To display this page, Firefox must send information that will repeat any action (such as a search or order confirmation) that was performed earlier."
with 2 options, RESEND CANCEL. Please tell me what should I do. Can't use GET as it displays my whole search query.

Comment: I read somewhere the use of **POST-REDIRECT-GET** but I'm not sure how to Practically implement that.

my code for checkbox:
`<form name=form1 method=post action=searchdb.php>`

Comment: have you tested in another browser?

Answer (score 1):

If you are perform some search to get information, I recommend to just use **GET**. **POST-REDIRECT-GET** will also display your search query.

If you use post, the browser will confirm that you really want to do a post once more.
Use GET to get data, use POST to operate the data, in my personal opinion.

Answer (score 0):

Quick and dirty: Store all the values of the check boxes in a $_Session[] array and check for that first.

```
if($_SESSION["CheckBox1"] === "on")
{
    // Do Stuff
}
else
{
    // Get $_POST[] Data and do stuff
    $_SESSION["CheckBox1"] = $_POST["CheckBox1"];
    ...
}
```

When the user submits the Form you first check if the $_SESSION has data otherwise put data in it and go about your normal work. If a reload happens then the $_SESSION values are used and not the now empty $_POST array.

Answer (score 0):

After posting the data, Redirect to the current page. That will cancel out the resend/cancel issue.

If your website is User-Profile based, you can have a look at the users data and return selected checked boxes.

OR

You can set a cookie value, via javascript [on checkbox click] or backend [when posting], this way you can store checked checkboxes and return it clicked on reload.

Answer (score 0):

This only happen when you try to REFRESH page after POST Request.

Bowser asks you what should it do: resend POST data or simply refresh page without POSTING (send GET only).

The same behaviour on Chrome. Opera doesn't asks, just resend previously sent POST data by default.

Answer (score 0):

Changed the method request type from POST to GET in my search form and got rid of the confirmation box..